# Adding SQL Server registered servers in Powershell

Tags: sql-server-2008, scripting, powershell

I am attempting to use Powershell v2 to add registered servers in SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

So far I have the following outline

```
add-pssnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
add-pssnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
##get-pssnapin

sl "SQLSERVER:\SQLRegistration\Database Engine Server Group"

new-item SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME -itemtype registration -Value "server=SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME;integrated security=false;User Id=SA;Password=foofoo"
```

The problem I have is with the registered server friendly name. We require slashes in it as we have named instances with the same names on different servers.

Regardless of what I try I get the following error message.

> The type is not a known type for the
>   file system. Only "file" and
>   "directory" can be specified

I have tried enclosing in quotes, using grave as an escape character. None of which works for me.

Cheers
David

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the encode-sqlname cmdlet which is part of the SqlServerCmdletSnapin100. Here's an example:

```
New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname "SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME") -itemtype registration -Value “server=MyServer;integrated security=true”
```

I have a couple of blog posts about registering servers here also:
http://sev17.com/2008/12/registering-sql-servers-in-2000-em-2005-ssms-and-2008-ssms/
and here
http://sev17.com/2009/01/dynamically-register-sql-instances-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008/